# karate.read json file in karate-config returns not an object

Tags: karate

In Karate 0.6.2, the following worked:

var myJson = JSON.parse(karate.read('classpath:myJson.json').jsonString());

However when upgrading to Karate 0.8.0, the above no longer seems to work, I believe jsonString() is no longer a function on the object returned by read.

I tried to assign the result of read directly to the myJson var but when I try to read values from the json, I get a not an object exception.

Doing a JSON.parse also doesn't work, since the result of read seems to be malformed json.

So, the question i have is, how do i read a json file on the classpath in Karate 0.8.0 from karate-config and assign it to a variable that I can actually interact with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read() function evaluates the file type and parse it internally in its native format, so you don't have to externally parse it.

```
var myJson = read('classpath:myJson.json' );
```

should work fine in karate-config.

Comment: exactly this. you should NEVER need to do `JSON.parse()` in karate at all

Comment: Right I tried this and the runtime still gave me an error claiming the assigned variable was not an object...

Comment: since you are upgrading from 0.6.2 I am assuming it could be a dependency issue (not sure on this). You can try deleting .m2\repository\com\intuit\karate folder from your user directory and run your code once again, it should download all dependency properly and run fine. If you still face the same issue please submit an issue - https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: unable to reproduce in a clean project so it's got to be something with my setup/dependencies. Appreciate the quick responses. Please consider this issue invalid/resolved.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When i karate.log the object, it's in string format, not object format.  Ex:  `{empty=true}` instead of `{empty: true}`